# ts.createProgram is generating an unexpected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am experiencing an unexpected output from ts.createProgram in my script. Instead of creating a single program object from the appropriated file, the function returns many objects with different sourcefile attributes (none of which corresponding to the one I was expected).

My script is a simplified version of one example provided in the official wiki of TypeScript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker

docGen.ts :

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as fs from "fs";

function generateDocumentation(
fileNames: string[],
options: ts.CompilerOptions): void{
    let program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options);

    for (const sourceFile of program.getSourceFiles()) {
        console.log(sourceFile.fileName);
    }
    return;
}

generateDocumentation(process.argv.slice(2), {
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
        module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS
    }
);
```

I have installed the latest version of nodejs and typescript", I am running this script on a Windows 10 cmd, in the nodejs install directory where I have added my script and a js file name "Workspace.js":

```
tsc docGen.ts --m commonjs
node docGen.js Workspace.js
```

[image: cmd output]

Notice that none of the logged sourcefile attributes correspond to my input "Workspace.js".

Why I am getting so much unexpected program objects ? What is wrong with my code ? Could it be an issue unrelated to the script ?

Answer (score 2):

These are all declaration files.

Notice that in the example you linked to, it includes:

```
// Visit every sourceFile in the program
  for (const sourceFile of program.getSourceFiles()) {
    if (!sourceFile.isDeclarationFile) {
      // Walk the tree to search for classes
      ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, visit);
    }
  }
```

It excludes declaration files.

That's not everything that isn't working with your program, but that explains those files.

Comment: Good point, it was indeed one of the issues. The other one was that this function doesn't work with .js target files, only .ts , something this didn't require: 

const sourceCode = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8');
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(fileName, sourceCode, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, true);